# Cannot get SpecFlow to work in Visual Studio 2010 no matter what I do!!!11

Tags: visual-studio-2010, specflow

When I add a reference in a Visual Studio 2010 project via NuGet for Specflow 1.9, I cannot add any features no matter what I do. I've restarted VS, restarted my PC, created new projects, etc. Nothing I do allows me to actually use SpecFlow. I.e. when I go to Project > Add New Item, I do not see any SpecFlow files in the Add New Item dialog.

It is worth noting that I do not have the "ItemTemplates" directory that should supposedly exist in the 
"C:\Program Files (x86)\TechTalk\SpecFlow\" directory.

It is also worth noting that I had Visual Studio 2012 Web Express installed, but I'm not sure why that would prevent feature files from showing up under Add > New Item in a VS 2010 project!

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to also install SpecFlow via the Visual Studio Extension Manager.

> Tools > Extension Manager

Installing via Nuget only gives you the reference to the SpecFlow dlls - it doesn't install the files for feature templates etc into Visual Studio.

Comment: I did that and it worked (kind of - I'm still having compatibility issues with NUnit vs MSTest).  I'm still curious (and terribly frustrated) with why this was needed.  I did not need to do it this way on my home PC last night, and the SpecFlow website specifically says to use NuGet.

Comment: Could you link to where it says that on the site?  Perhaps it needs updating.  SpecFlow has two elements - the Visual Studio templates, and the dlls used in a project.  On your home PC you must have installed SpecFlow itself somehow.  Nuget packages can only amend your solutions/projects, it can't actually install things such as file/project templates into Visual Studio.  These things require installation through the Extension Manager.

Comment: 99% sure I followed the same process on my home PC and work PC.  I.e. I didn't use Extension Manager to get it to work at home.  The setup instruction page I was referring to is: http://www.specflow.org/specflownew/ProjectSetupGuide.html

Answer (score 0):

Try to install SpecFlow using Package Manager Console like

> PM> Install-Package SpecFlow

More about [Package Manager Console](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/start-here/using-the-package-manager-console)

Comment: It installed just fine that way, but same problem still exists.  Installing via PM Console should be not different than doing it through the GUI anyway.

Comment: No errors.  It runs just fine, but then the SpecFlow feature files do not show up under Project > Add New Item.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to ngm's answer.

The NuGet package gives you everything you need to run SpecFlow, for example on a build server.

The VSIX gives you what you need to edit scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, I got both SpecFlow scenario creation and running of NUnit-based tests working after installing both SpecFlow AND NUnit packages, both via NuGet and also via "Tools > Extension Manager" menu. Until I installed NUnit via "Tools > Extension Manager" I was unable to see execution and reports of any tests/scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

For VS 2013, after I added SpecFlow via nuget, I wasn't able to see the templates as well.  I fixed this by:

- Downloading a file from 
  [SpecFlow for Visual Studio 2013](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/90ac3587-7466-4155-b591-2cd4cc4401bc).
- Click Download.
- After you download the file (e.g. TechTalk.SpecFlow.Vs2013Integration.vsix), double click it and it will start the installation process.
- Close VS 2013.  After you start it back up again, you'll be able to see the templates.

Hope this might help other folks too.

Answer (score 0):

After using the package manager to install the .dlls, you need to use tools->"Add-in Manager" to add in the Specflow templates.